# Misspelling Variable Names. Best ways to avoid this sort of error?

Tags: python

Coming from a background of compiled languages without dynamic typing, something I find frustrating in Python is the potential for inadvertently introducing a new variable name via misspelling.

I had an example of this a few days ago where the code went something like this:

```
received = False

while not received:
   ...
   ...
   ...
   recieved = (some_conditional_statments)
   ...
   ...

print some_results
```

Here *received* was a boolean variable that was supposed to be set to true upon the terminating condition of the loop being reached. Obviously though, in this case it got stuck in an infinite loop due to the misspelt variable (rec**ie**ved)

Obviously a compiler will pick up mistakes like this straight away, I just wondering what techniques people use to help avoid errors like this in Python?

Comment: Effective communication is important for programmers, and the easiest way to spell consistently is to spell correctly (and know that you're doing so). In short, I avoid this sort of thing by not ever typing `recieved` because of knowing it's wrong. I guess you could say it's a matter of discipline.

Comment: That's not a very helpful comment Karl. Anyone can mis-type a word by transposing two keystrokes, even if they know the correct spelling. Your answer of  "simply never making any mistakes in the first place" is just plain unhelpful.

Comment: You're welcome to feel that way, and it's why I left a comment rather than an answer. Nevertheless, it's what works for me.

Comment: It's ok Karl. I understand where you were coming from. How about we call that one "method 0", or "the fundamental method of error control". Just never make any mistakes. Easy. :)

Answer (score 8):

Use a decent linter, and test your code using automated testing (unit tests, etc.). Most IDEs and text editors can be set up to run a linter automatically.

I recommend using [`flake8`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/flake8); it combines the output of the [`pep8` style checker](http://pep8.readthedocs.org/en/latest/), the [`pyflakes` linter](https://launchpad.net/pyflakes) (which would catch the above error, it'll tell you `recieved` is assigned to but never used elsewhere) and will tell you if your code is getting too complex (using the [McCabe Cyclomatic complexity metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclomatic_complexity)).

Comment: Thanks Martijn, I'm taking a look at Flake8 now.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [pychecker](http://pychecker.sourceforge.net/) for this kind of thing.

There's a [question about python linters here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5611776/what-are-the-comprehensive-lint-checkers-for-python), you should check it out.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into pychecker.  BTW. Is this what Martijn refers to as a linter"?

Comment: @Stuart Yes, it's like a linter. I'll add a link into my answer

Comment: Unfortunately, `pychecker` *executes* your python code; if your code makes changes in external systems (writes files, commits to a database, etc.) that is *dangerous* behaviour for a code checking tool. Better stick to a static tool + unit tests.

Comment: Yes I just discovered that Martijn. Pychecker was not useful for finding this particular "infinite loop" problem when I used it as a test case. It just tried to execute the code and got stuck in the same infinite loop.